# Is there a way to inherit ffmpeg_movie class in PHP?

Tags: php, class, ffmpeg

When I run the following code I get `B` as expected:

```
class A {
    public function __construct($file){}
}

class B extends A {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct('test.flv');
    }
}

$b = new B();
print get_class($b);
```

However, consider a slightly modified version of this code (here `ffmpeg_movie` class is a part of http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net library):

```
class B extends ffmpeg_movie {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct('test.flv');
    }
}

$b = new B();
print get_class($b);
```

It returns `ffmpeg_movie` instead of `B`. Furthermore, it turns out that methods defined in `B` class aren’t accessible when using `$b` object:

```
class B extends ffmpeg_movie {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct('test.flv');
    }

    public function test() {
        print 'ok';
    }
}

$b = new B();
$b->test();
```

`Fatal error: Call to undefined method ffmpeg_movie::test() in .../test.php on line 13`

What exactly is going on here and is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn’t find out what was the origin of the problem. I managed to solve it though by not extending ffmpeg_movie class directly and instead using `__call`, `__get` and `__set` PHP magic methods to mimic inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

This is an undefined behavior of get_class() and its been discussed many times before.

As of PHP 4.3.0 the constant **CLASS** exists and contains the class name.

Until somebody comes with a solution, you might fiddle around with something like this inside your B class:

```
public function whoAmI() {
    return __CLASS__;
}
```

OR (from googling) MAYBE

```
public function whoAmI() {
    return getClass($this);
}
```

Comment: It’s not just get_class function bug. 'B' class methods aren’t accessible either (see updated question).